# How can one incorporate JSON data with the returned HTML on the first request to the home page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

My scenario is this - the user asks for the home page and then the javascript code of the page executes an ajax GET request to the same server to get some object.

The server keeps the home page as a jade template.

So, right now it takes two roundtrips to load the home page:

1. GET the home page
2. GET the JSON object

I am OK with it, but just out of curiosity - what are my options to incorporate the object requested later into the initial GET request of the home page?

I see one way is to have a hidden html element, which inner HTML would be the string representation of the object. A bit awkward, but pretty simple on the server side, given that the home page jade template is preprocessed anyway.

What are my other options?

Please, note that I am perfectly aware that sparing this one roundtrip does not really matter. I am just curious about the techniques.

Comment: how about caching the actual object to a javascript variable, or, better yet, save it to a cookie?

Comment: Why would it be in a cookie? I do not need it sent back by the browser with each request. Caching to a variable? Is it like what bfavaretto suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to always return a JSON object, then the HTML for your home page would be the value of some property on this object. This would probably require some changes on your client-side logic, though.

One more option: instead of a hidden HTML input/textarea containing a JSON string, the home page code could contain a script block where an object literal is declared as a variable. Something like this:

```
<script>
var myObj = ... // Your JSON string here.
                // myObj will be an object literal, and you won't need
                // to parse the JSON.
</script>
```

Comment: Returning JSON from the start is not an option - the user loads an HTML page, (s)he cannot get back json.

Comment: @mark I thought both request were ajax. So, scratch the first option. What about the second?

Comment: It looks simple, checking it now. Do you know how to do it in a jade template?

Comment: No, I never used jade, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The initial GET request will retrieve just that document. You can have additional documents loaded defined as scripts at the bottom of your page, so you don't need to do a XHR, for the initial load.

For instance:

```
GET /index.html
//At the bottom you have a <script src="/somedata.js"></script>

GET /somedata.js
//here you define you var myObj = {}.... as suggested by bfavertto
```

Depending on which server side technology are you using, this could be for instance in MVC3

```
public partial class SomeDataController : BaseController
{
    public virtual ContentResult SomeData()
    {
        var someObject = //GET the JSON
        return Content("var myObj = " + someObject, "application/javascript");
    }
}
```

Comment: The object is fetched from the database. I cannot prepare a file beforehand. What is your suggestion?

Comment: It depends what you are using in the server side. Which technology are you using?

Comment: Node+Mongo. The code is javascript, but it cannot be executed on the client side. The object must be fetched on the server side.

Comment: Which nodejs server/framework are you using? Jade is just for templating, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have already managed to get bfavaretto suggestion working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the Json data inside a hidden tag in your HTML. At runtime, your javascript reads the data from this hidden tag instead of making a Json call (or make the call if this data is not available).

```
<!--the contents of this div will be filled at server side with a Json string-->
<div id="my-json-data" style="display:hidden">[...json data...]</div>
```

on document ready:

```
var jsonStr = document.getElementById( "my-json-data" ).innerHTML;
```